# Is there a pattern between the mass of a body and the mass of orbiting objects around it?

Tags: the-moon, solar-system, earth, the-sun, natural-satellites

I was looking at Wikipedia's [Solar system page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_system#Structure_and_composition), and it says that Sun represents 99.86% of the whole solar system mass. I found that pretty huge.

So i calculated ratio of masses : Earth / ([Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) + [Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)) and it's about 98.78%.

I did the same with Jupiter : Jupiter / ([Jupiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter) + [Io](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_%28moon%29) + [Europa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_%28moon%29) + [Ganymede](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_%28moon%29) + [Callisto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callisto_%28moon%29)) and it's about 99.97% (I ignored small satellites).

- Why is it such a high ratio in this 3 examples?
- Is 1% a regular number for satellites' mass?
- It is simple gravitation maths ?

I understand that one body has to be much more massive in order to be a planet-satellite system, otherwise it's a [double planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_planet) system. But I would have thought 90% would be enough.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no pattern on 1%. There are cases of [double stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_star) and (allegedly) of [double planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_planets).

In our Solar System, Charon has a mass of 11.6% of that of Pluto.